# How to verify if a Job ran another Job using @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-batch

I'm running a Batch Job in a `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@Autowired
private JobRunner jobRunner;

jobRunner.runNowForTests("X_Job");
```

And I have a listener that runs `Y_Job` after `X_Job` finishes:

```
class JobFinishedEventListener  {

    @Autowired
    private JobRunner jobRunner;

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        jobRunner.runNow("Y_Job");
    }

}
```

My `@Test` function is checking that `X_Job` completed successfully like this:

```
assertJobStatus(X_Job_Execution, COMPLETED);
```

However, I don't know how to test if `Y_Job` ran successfully since I don't have the reference to its execution. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Hmm, true. But I still want to know to accomplish this, it's a code I didn't wrote. Like, maybe there's a way to get all the jobs ran in the current context?

Comment: `I have a listener that runs Y_Job after X_Job finishes`: any reason to do that instead of running two jobs in sequence? I don't think running the next job in a listener#afterJob of the current job is the way to go, but I could be missing something.

Comment: ok I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see why one would run the next job using `listener#afterJob` of the current job. This should be functionally the same as the following (using a synchronous task executor in job launcher):

```
JobExecution jobExecution1 = jobLauncher.run(job_x, params_x);
JobExecution jobExecution2 = jobLauncher.run(job_y, params_y);
```

This approach allows you to get a reference to both job executions and add assertions as needed.

Comment: Wow, We are definitely changing our code. I actually never asked myself if it was sync or async. I just saw that the person who wrote the code was using afterJob and I always assumed it was async, but it is not. As you said, the afterJob is not necessary after all. Thanks. However not selecting as accepted answer since I'm still curious about how to know if job_y ran with current approach

Comment: I can't help with your current approach because you did not share what `jobRunner.runNow` and `jobRunner.runNowForTests` return (a void type or JobExecution). Even if it returns a JobExecution, it is still difficult to get access to it from the listener and assert on it. My rule of thumb: if it is difficult to test, it is probably poorly designed (You said you did not write that code, and good to know that you are changing that).